# CakePHP: How do I count the number of hasMany records in a find?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, mysql-error-1111

I have two models, `Post` hasMany `Comment`. How do I select all `Post` that have less than two `Comment`?

I tried using a `find` with `'fields'=>array('COUNT(Comment.id) as numComments','Post.*')`, (and then doing a `numComments < 2` in `'conditions'`). But, I get a `Unknown column 'Comment.id' in 'field list'` error.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've gotten CakePHP to generate this query:

```
SELECT `Post`.*, FROM `posts` AS `Post` 
    LEFT JOIN comments AS `Comment` ON (`Post`.`id` = `Comment`.`text_request_id`)  
    WHERE COUNT(`Comment`.`id`) < 2 
    GROUP BY `Comment`.`post_id` 
    LIMIT 10
```

But I get an error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function` on the `COUNT` function.

**EDIT:
Resolved, use the HAVING COUNT instead of WHERE COUNT.**

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my SQL is a bit rusty, I was just about to suggest `HAVING`. :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    var $name = "Post";
    var $hasMany = array('Comment'=>array('counterCache'=>true));
}
```

add comment_count fields into posts

an that's all :-)

Comment: Just to let you know: this answer ended two days of frustrated searching how to do just this. +1000 for you!

Answer (score 1):

In raw SQL, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT Post.*
FROM Post LEFT JOIN Comment ON Post.id = Comment.post_id
GROUP BY Comment.post_id
HAVING COUNT(Comment.id) < 2
```

Most of these are easily translated to Cake:

```
array(
    'having' => array('COUNT(Comment.id) <' => 2),
    'group'  => array('Comment.post_id')
)
```

Cake does not automatically join hasMany tables though, this is something you'll need to do manually. Have a look at [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/872/Joining-tables) for the details.

#### Edit:

You can do a `having` clause as follows:

```
array(
    'group' => 'Comment.post_id HAVING COUNT(Comment.id) < 2'
)
```

The limitations are `string` only for the group and cant be done without the group by. Cake 3 will probably include more `SQL` syntax such as `HAVING`

Comment: CakePHP 1.3 unfortunately doesn't have the 'having' index in the array.

Comment: You're right. -_-;; This may be one case where writing SQL by hand is preferred. Alternatively, @Aziz' suggestion of count-caching is actually the better and faster (query-wise) way.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested:
here's the doc about counterCache http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#belongsto
and here's more about adding multiple counterCache fields http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-countercache