# SQL select distinct count and data from table

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a table like

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id | order_id | service_id |
+----+----------+------------+
| 1  | 3423343  | 123        |
+----+----------+------------+
| 2  | 3432356  | 124        |
+----+----------+------------+
| 3  | 2345643  | 123        |
+----+----------+------------+
| 4  | 2313343  | 125        |
+----+----------+------------+
```

What I want to get is the count of each `service_id` which will give output like this

```
+------------+------+
| service_id | cout |
+------------+------+
| 123        | 2    |
+------------+------+
| 124        | 1    |
+------------+------+
| 125        | 1    |
+------------+------+
```

and also to arrange it in `Highest -> Lowest` order

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2

Comment: select service_id, count(1) cout
from thetable
group by service_id 
order by cout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP: How do I count the number of hasMany records in a find?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123176/cakephp-how-do-i-count-the-number-of-hasmany-records-in-a-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by on column `service_id` and count the rows of every group.

```
SELECT 
    service_id, 
    COUNT(service_id) AS `Count` 
FROM 
    tablename -- your table name
GROUP BY 
    service_id
ORDER BY
    `Count` DESC;
```